# Can I compare a file from a Git branch with the same file of another Git branch in Sublime

Tags: git, phpstorm, sublimetext3

Is there a way to see the changes in a file when compared with the same file of another Git branch in Sublime? I mean if there is something similar to `Compare with Branch` command of PhpStorm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems git will introduce the Sublime Merge "smerge" in the next release v2.22.0. As for now, install the package `Sublimerge 3` first and then see this answer for the rest, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23528969/6330106. `git difftool branch_foo branch_bar -- file_baz` will invoke the diff tool.

Comment: You can diff two branches against each other and then look for the file in question to see what's different between the two. I'm not sure you can do it for just a single file though (since you're comparing commits).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me as said by @ElpieKay:

```
git difftool branch_foo branch_bar -- file_baz
```